# Python Dataframe : Std using rolling period

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a Dataframe with a Date column (daily, from 2000 to 2023) and a Value column.
What I need is to extract the global mean and std for all the year per days. Particularity is that I need each time to consider the day as a rolling period of 3 days. So if I want the global mean for all the 05 of Jan, in fact I need to do the mean for all the 4, 5 and 6 of Jan. Because of that, a simple groupby(Day,Month) cannot be done, because the 5 of Jan will be need in the computation of the 4 and the 6 also.

Initially I just decided to do a loop over the 365 days, compute the day before and after, do a filtration of the dataframe, and compute mean / std. Result : computation is just way too long.

For the mean I have found a solution quite easily : =

```
df['mean'] = df['Value'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1, center=True).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df['count'] = df['Value'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1, center=True).count().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Month_Day']).agg({'mean': 'sum', 'count': 'sum'}).reset_index()
df_grouped['avg'] = df_grouped['mean'] / df_grouped['count']
df_grouped = df_grouped.drop(['mean', 'count'], axis=1)
df= pd.merge(test, df_grouped, on=['ADM3_CODE', 'Month_Day'], how='left')
```

I just recompute the avg with the sum of all the value firstly for the rolling period of 3 days, and then I can dothe group by (Day-Month) and recompute properly the mean.

Now the issue is for std : to do the same, I need to substract the mean previously computed for the 5 of Jan, but to the 4th and 6th. Then in the rolling period, it is not just a sum or other simple stuff, but I need to substract the corresponding mean of the center of the rolling period, do the square of difference, and then only sum all that.

a quick example could be :

```
Date,Value,Avg
2020-01-01,5,5
2020-01-02,6,4
2020-01-03,7,6
2020-01-04,8,3
```

for 2020-01-01 :

```
 (5-5)**2 + (6-5)**2 = 1 (here the 5 is from Avg for 2020-01-01)
```

for 2020-01-02

```
 (5-4)**2 + (6-4)**2 + (7-4)**2 = 14 (here the 4 is from Avg for 2020-01-02)
```

once the computation explained above done, I'll be able to do the gorup by just like for the mean

Comment: Don't use the tag [tag:std] with Python, read the tag description carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `.rolling`, which is a great idea. Why don't you just apply `.rolling().std()`?

```
df['std'] = df['Value'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1, center=True).std()
```

Same goes for your (currently very manual) calculation of the mean: Why don't you use `.rolling().mean()` directly, but instead calculate it manually with `sum` and `count`?

If it is about respecting the data boundaries (e.g., not going over the month end, or the year end), then you could just group the data into smaller batches first, and do the rolling only on that group/subset (`groupby().rolling().std()`). But in either case, the calculation itself can be done with `.rolling().std()` directly, no?